# accessing network over wifi, but unable to set router as repeater?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, repeater

I am dealing with this issue currently, where I access the internal company network with a cable connection. 
Others are using a separate wifi connection (not part of the internal network).

I want to make the network accessible over the wifi router, so my plan was to set up the router to serve as a repeater / extender.

Issues:

1. when I try to change the LAN IP (to be within the main network, I get this:

   *Error code: 5008
   WAN IP address and LAN IP address cannot be in a same subnet. Please input another IP address.*
2. The DHCP is disabled, but when I do ipconfig/all in cmd, it doesn't look like it. Attached images compare results from

   a) having cable A directly attached to PC

   b) cable A attached to the router, PC connected wirelessly to the router
3. When I try to setup a static route on the router (with the root network details) I get this:

   *Error code: 4011
   Destination Network address cannot be inside the subnet of WAN IP address, please enter again.*

Router: TP-LINK AC1750

I am out of ideas. Any help ? Quite urgently...

**Goal: have the same network config when connected to the router as when connected directly with cable A. Be able to access the internal network (printers, shares etc.) over wifi.**

[image: network]
[image: wan config on router]
[image: ipconfig cable]
[image: ipconfig wireless]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using TPLINK-AC1750 RE450 Wifi Range Extender, it sounds like you have it configured in the wrong operational mode. You want it to be in 'access' point mode. From the [manufacturer's documentation](http://www.tp-link.us/res/down/doc/RE450(US)_V1_UG.pdf):

> 4.2. Transform Your Existing Wired Network to a Wireless One The extender can work as an access point, transforming your existing wired
>   network to a wireless one.
>   4.2.1. To Set Up the Extender as an Access Point
>   1. Visit http://tplinkrepeater.net, and log in with the username and password you set for the extender. 
>   2. Click Mode in the top right corner of the page. Select Access Point and click Save. The extender will reboot and switch to Access Point
>   mode.
>   3. After rebooting, connect the extender to your modem or wired router via an Ethernet cable.
>   4. Visit http://tplinkrepeater.net, and log in with the usename and password you set for the extender. 
>   5. Go to Quick Setup to configure your extender.
>  
>    1 ) Configure your wireless settings and click Next.
>  2 ) Confirm the information and
>   click Finish. Now, you can enjoy the Wi-Fi.

There is a chance that you have an older version of firmware that doesn't support this mode; check your firmware version and update if you don't have the current release (at this time, it is 
RE450(US)_V1_151203_US dated 3/12/15). The latest firmware can be [found here](http://www.tp-link.us/download/RE450.html#Firmware).

The firmware update process is straightforward, here is an excerpt from the same user's guide:

> 5.4. Upgrade the Firmware TP-LINK is dedicated to improving, richening the product features and giving you a better network
>   experience. You can download the latest firmware file from the Support
>   page of our website www.tp-link.com and upgrade the firmware to the
>   latest version. 
> Note:
>   1. Make sure the latest firmware file is matched with the hardware version (as shown in the download section of the Support page).
>   2. Make sure that you have a stable connection between the extender and your computer. It is NOT recommended to upgrade the firmware
>   wirelessly.
>   3. Backup your extender configuration.
>   4. Do NOT power off the extender during the firmware upgrade. 
> To upgrade the firmware:
>   1. Download the latest firmware file for the extender from our website www.tp-link. com.
>   2. Visit http://tplinkrepeater.net, and log in with the username and password you set for the extender.
>   3. Go to Settings > System Tools > Firmware Upgrade.
>   4. Click Browse to locate the downloaded new firmware file, and then click Upgrade. 
>   5. Wait a few minutes for the upgrade and reboot.

There is also a chance that the router model number is incorrect, as the configuration menu screenshot that you posted does not match those shown in the documentation. It's possibly due to you having an older firmware revision, but make sure you confirm that part number. Update your question if it is not the TPLINK AC1750.

Occasionally, manufacturers - especially networking focused ones - like to reuse part numbers and create a new hardware revision instead, even though it is a nearly completely new product. That does not appear to be the case for this part, as I only see one HW revision of the product.

In any event, the answer to this question is based almost entirely around the specific router / extender you are trying to configure, as they there is absolutely no 'standard' consumer router / extender configuration scheme.

Comment: thank you for the brilliant answer! Much appreciated.
For some reason though, I didn't even have to undertake any of those steps. The router got somehow messed up from the previous settings, so I had to do a reset. And suddenly, I was able to access the network by default. Strange.
The weird thing is, that I don't think I am part of the actual network - in the Network discovery on my notebook, I only see the router and my notebook. Also I cannot find the network printers. 
But when I manually access the server, or add the printer name as it's shared on the network, it works.

Comment: I can also add the current ipconfig output, or the router settings if that helps to clarify the situation. I haven't checked the system routing table before the reboot, but I am guessing that has something to do with it as well.

Comment: I think you'll be better served if you can configure it as an access point rather than a router - I would be concerned about possibly overlapping DHCP leases, not to mention the mess that occurs with multiple DHCP servers on a single network segment (its a race to see which server wins). Its worth the small hassle now to prevent a potential issue in the future.